# Launch WPF UI on user console connection

Tags: c#, windows, server, remote-desktop, winlogon

I have written a WPF application that I want to show (the UI) every time a user logs into a server. It must show on user login but also when a user connects to a existing console session via RDP.

I have no trouble with new user login.

The issue I'm having is invoking my application when a user connects to the console session, a existing user session on the server.

The most obvious way would be to setup a scheduled task, there is specific support for this but the UI will only show the UI for the user who it is 'running as', as defined in task scheduler. So I may have not be able to use this as it must launch and show the UI to any user who connects to an existing console session.

How can I achieve this, to detect / launch an interactive application when a user connects via RDP to an already logged in console session? I'm stuck.

Thanks

Comment: You can set your application in `Windows Startup`. There are some problem with Win 8 and Win 10 on setting Startup applications but its still a solution. 
Search for `Windows Startup` on Google.

Comment: Thanks, however, windows startup will not launch the application when a user connects to an existing user session over RDP.

Comment: as a fun solution, you can watch mouse movements. you can make your window `Top Most` if mouse is moved after a long period.